# Unable to diminish subword mode

Tags: mode-line, subword-mode

I have `global-subword-mode` enabled and `diminish` installed. I have

```
(diminish 'subword-mode)
```

in my `init.el`. Despite this, subword-mode keeps appearing in the mode-line when I start emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes `diminish` can be tricky. Some things work only in an `with-eval-after-load` form, and some only work in the mode's hook.

In this case, I use:

```el
;; This is because the mode is initialized after the file is loaded?
;; I'm not too sure. I took a peek at the code, and it looks pretty normal.
(with-eval-after-load 'subword
  (diminish 'subword-mode))
(global-subword-mode +1)
```

This works in `emacs -Q`, so it should work for you without any problems.